# Sequelize OR clause with multiple models

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm looking for a way to write a query using [SequelizeJS](http://sequelizejs.com) that contains an OR clause which references more than one model (table).

I would like the sql to end up looking something like this:

```
select *
from Department
inner join Office on Department.OfficeId = Office.Id
where Office.Name like 'spokane%'
or Department.Name like 'spokane%'
```

I've seen similar questions about filtering the joined table, with answers that look like the following.

```
options.include = [{
    model: offices.model,
    where: {
        name: {
           $like: 'spokane%'
        }
    }
  }];

options.where = Sequelize.or(
    {
       'name': {
          $like: 'spokane%'
        }
    });

departments.findAndCount(options);
```

However this doesn't produce the correct sql.

It spits out something like this:

```
select *
from Department
inner join Office on Department.OfficeId = Office.Id and Office.name like 'spokane%'
where Department.name like 'spokane%'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
options.where = {
  $or: [
    sequelize.where(sequelize.col('office.name'), { $like: 'foo'}),
    sequelize.where(sequelize.col('department.name'), { $like: 'foo'})
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had to modify the include to make it required, but then it worked great. `{ model: offices.model, required: true }`

Comment: Thanks @JuanitoCROM , the `required` option helped me